# not recognizing error messages specified for a custom validation in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

i made a custom validation in laravel 4.2 and put in the app/start/global.php and my code there is this

```
Validator::extend('captcha', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
 $captcha = $_SESSION["captcha"];
 return $value == $captcha;
});

Validator::extend('cSY', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
 $appnd = "SY " . $value ."-". ($value + 1);
 $chkSY = DB::table('dbo_schoolyear')
          ->where('SchoolYear' , '=' , $appnd)
          ->count();
 if($chkSY)
 {
    return false;
 }
 else
 {
    return true;
 }

});
```

then in my controller here is my code

```
$rules = array(
        'nsy' => 'required|integer|min:2005|cSY'
    );  

    $messages = array(
        'nsy.required'  => 'Please enter Starting Year.',
        'nsy.integer'   => 'Starting year can only contain integer values',
        'nsy.min'       => 'School Year Minimum is 2005',
        'nsy.cSY'       => 'School Year exists'
    );
```

The validation works properly but the message that i declared in the messages array is not being recognized. I dont know why. the error it outputs is validation.c_sy any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: As a wild guess I suspect a camelCase issue. Try changing `cSY` to `csy`.

Comment: thanks! i worked! :) please put this to the answers :)

Comment: I'm glad my wild guess was right. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a camelCase issue: `cSY` is being interpreted as `c_sy`.

Simply change `cSY` to `csy`.